# Why are my NiFi 1.11.1 processors hanging on tasks?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a set of process groups running happily on a 1.8.0 NiFi server.  I spun up an instance of NiFi 1.11.1 on a separate, but similar server, and templated over the same process groups.  On the new 1.11 server, the processors (all of them, no apparent difference by type) handle a small batch of tasks and then hang on one task for hours.

Restarting the processors has no noticeable effect, restarting the NiFi instance itself generally gets the processors to play nicely for a minute or two before the problem resurfaces.  There are no errors in the logs, bumping up memory had no effect, processor use isn't going above 20%.

I have been comparing to the running server, the only differences have been the newer NiFi version and the operating system's open files limit (that did cause error statements in the log before I updated to match the working server).  I have only checked what I could think to check, of course, so please suggest anything I may have missed.

I am very new to NiFi, so if there are diagnostics or similar that I could use to get more information, please let me know.

Comment: You should generate one or more [thread dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434957/nifi-blocked-hanging#comment93872430_53434957) to determine where the application is blocked. The open file limit will definitely affect NiFi, as it often requires many files to be simultaneously open.

Comment: The file limit did indeed cause problems before I updated it to match the working server.  The thread dump lists most of the threads as waiting or timed waiting, with a smattering of runnable.  The runnables all report "Number of Locked Synchronizers: 1".  Is that something I should be worried about?

Comment: Please either share the thread dump content in your question or send it to dev@nifi.apache.org if you need further help.

Comment: The thread dump was too big to edit into the comment, so I've put it here: https://pastebin.com/A6SyWGsu

Comment: What kind of tasks are causing which processors to hang? Are you using `ListenHTTP` or `HandleHttpRequest` processors? How many threads do you have configured for NiFi to run?

Comment: I really wish I would have found that global thread setting earlier.  It's set to 10 for timer-driven and 1 for event-driven while the working production server has 300 for both.  EDIT: That did the trick.  If you'll add this as an answer, I'll happily accept it.  Also, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of steps recommended (read *required* for non-trivial deployments) during Apache NiFi configuration. In this case, the specific setting that was restricting behavior was the Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count, which was causing resource contention with a high number of processors on the system.

Additional resources:

- [NiFi Admin Guide: Configuration Best Practices](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices)
- [NiFi User Guide: Monitoring of DataFlow](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#monitoring) - Describes monitoring status of individual components, including assigned threads
- [NiFi User Guide: Summary Page](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Summary_Page) - Describes comprehensive view of component behavior and processing statistics
- [Cloudera Community: Understanding NiFi max thread pools and processor concurrent task settings](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Understanding-NiFi-max-thread-pools-and-processor-concurrent/ta-p/248920) - Matt Clarke writes about how the thread pools work and how to configure them to maximize performance

Answer (score 2):

Per @Andy, under Settings -> Controller Settings -> General are two options, Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count and Maximum Event Driven Thread Count.  These default to 10 and 1, respectively.  For any significant number of processors, this is insufficient, so these values need to be increased.  In my case, that meant bumping them both up to 300.

Comment: Event Driven is not a recommended component scheduling setting, so you should be fine with a smaller number for that thread count.